# Android Emulator size issue

Tags: android-emulator, command-line, android-sdk

I'm having some issues managing/running AVDs from the commandline.  Whatever device I create/run seems to get cropped and displayed wrongly (see below).  I've tried various devices and settings (`-scale`) and have looked at the avd config files (they just seem to get reset after I make a change).

How can I fix this?

System Info:

- Windows 10;
- Latest Android SDK (manual install - no Android Studio);
- Android Version: 23

[image: emulator screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you select the right device resolution and screen size

There are a variety of options for example:

- dpi (1440 x 2560)
- xxhdpi (1080 x 1920)
- tvdpi (800 x1280)
- xhdpi (1080 x1920)

In my setup (API 23)

Here is my configuration:

- 5 inch screen size
- Density 480
- Monitor dpi 96

Can you check if these values correct you problem, I suggest you try from GUI this time:

See image:

[image: a]

To start from GUI go to the folder where android sdk was extracted for example:

```
C:\Users\Test\Android\android-sdk\AVD Manager.exe
```

Comment: I don't think the GUI is available in the sdk-only version, but I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: Also in GUI toggle the option: Scale to real size, you need to disable it, if it was enabled

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this matter?

Comment: Yeah, I caved and used the Android Studio installer. Works fine now, but seems odd that the stand alone SDK doesn't... I'll give you the answer, but it's gonna need more investigation I think.

Comment: Seems strange, but be welcome to answer your own question when you find the solution.  If I get something I will update you too.